# How does Azure Machine Learning (AML) decide what 'type' an input is in the training data as this is causing an error

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

We have trained a network in AML based on a large training data-set with many inputs. For one of the inputs all the training data supplied was an integer amount. Nowhere in our model do we specify the type of the input fields and this input is a continuous field as opposed to a discrete one.

However in use in production, the AML web service was called with this input supplied as a decimal instead of a real and it threw an error:

```
Error Content: {"error":{"code":"BadArgument","message":"Invalid argument provided.","details":[{"code":"InputParseError","target":"input1","message":"Parsing of input vector failed.  Verify the input vector has the correct number of columns and data types.  Additional details: Input string was not in a correct format.."}]}}
```

If I edit the call to change the input from being a decimal to an integer it works perfectly.

Before we go change either the model or the calling code i would like to understand how/why this error is occurring?

I have done some research and cant seem to find anything that explains how AML decides the input "type" and whether it can be changed in the model.

Answer (score 0):

Well persistent searching the net has revealed the correct answer (for me anyway). Essentially I needed to add the "Edit Metadata" module to my experiment then use the column selector to select the column in question and set its data type from integer to floating point. It seems that AML detected that all the training data was of type integer and hence automatically selected this data type on import of the training data.

See here for more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/studio-module-reference/edit-metadata